# How to connect an existing nodejs server app to Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, node.js, azure

Can anyone please advise:

I have an existing nodejs server running on azure, running node 10.14 on Linux. The project code is on github and when I push changes they are automatically pushed to azure.

I have set up a database server and database though the Azure portal and can query it through the Azure portal.

I want to modify the nodejs server to conect to the database, I have the connection string code etc. but just the act of adding the line:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

will stop the server form running as presumably I have not installed mysql on the machine which is running the server in the Azure cloud.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: Could you please tell me which database you use? Azure SQL database or Azure database for Mysql? Besides, do you host you web app on Azure app service?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's an Azure SQL database and yes, I host my app on azure also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, you do not add the package in your `package.json` file and install the package in your project. Besides, if you want to connect Azure SQL server database, we can use package [`mssqql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

For example

1. My `package.json` file

```
{
....
  
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mssql": "^6.2.0",
        "request": "^2.88.2"
    }

}
```

2. code

```
const router = express.Router()
const sql = require('mssql')


const config = {

  user: "<user name>",
  password: "<password>",
  server: "<your SQL server name>.database.windows.net",
  port: 1433,
  database: "test",
  connectionTimeout: 3000,
  parseJSON: true,
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    enableArithAbort: true
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3000
  }
};
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  
  await poolConnect;
  try {
    const request = pool.request(); 
    const result = await request.query('select 1 as number')
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result.recordset);
    
} catch (err) {
    console.error('SQL error', err);
    res.send(err);
}
});
```

3. Test.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. It put me on the right track. Thinngs are working now. Mitch.

Comment: @user3738290 Since it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?