# Express App on Azure Web App gives error 500 when any route contains a connection to a database

Tags: sql-server, express, azure-web-app-service

Good morning. Recently, I created an express app using `npx express-generator --ejs` and am trying to host it in a web app on Azure app services (currently using a free trial subscription until I am finished with testing)

Originally, the app displayed completely fine out of the box with the files left as they originally generated, and I was able to edit index.ejs to display my web page as html on the main directory for the site. However, when I try to add database calls to my mssql database to any route, the entire webpage gives a 500 error after being deployed to Azure. My web.config file is being generated automatically using the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in my app. Currently, the application works in full when hosted locally, including the database calls I need. It is only when I am trying to incorporate these routes on the Azure app that I run into this error.

Here is my code for one of my routes that I am trying to connect to the database with:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')


const db = {
  server: "server",
  database: "database",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  options: {
      trustedConnection: true,     
  }
}

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


  sql.connect(db).then(newPool => {
    pool = newPool;
    var inputOne =''
    inputOne ="'%"+req.query.name+"%'"
    return pool.request().query(`Select FullName from table where FullName like `+ inputOne) 
}).then(result => {
    result = result.recordset
    try {
    } catch (error) {
        result[0] = {FullName: 'No Results Found' }
    }
    console.log(result)
    res.json(result);
    pool && pool.close();


}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    pool && pool.close();
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am trying to pass a parameter through a form box in the HTML for my webpage. I will provide my HTML contained in my index.ejs file below as well (with my styling omitted to save space and time):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
<div class="search">
Page text content
                </br></br>
              
                <form action="/process_get" method="GET">
       <input placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name"><br>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
      <button onclick="location.reload()">Refresh</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="downloads">
      <button id="downloadResults">Download results as a PDF</button>
        <script> 
          document.getElementById("downloadResults").addEventListener("click", saveResults);
          function saveResults() {
            const downloaddata = new FormData(form);

            fetch('/getnames?' + new URLSearchParams(downloaddata))
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                const pdf = new jsPDF();
                var pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
                var height = 10
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  height += 7
                  if (height >= pageHeight-10) {
                    pdf.addPage()
                    height=10
                  }
                  pdf.text(data[i].FullName ,10 , height)
                }
                const name = document.getElementById('name').value
                pdf.save(`Save${name}.pdf`)
              })
          }
        </script>

      <button id="downloadAll">Download entire list as a PDF</button>
        <script> 
          document.getElementById("downloadAll").addEventListener("click", saveResults);
          function saveResults() {
            const formData = new FormData(form);

            fetch('/getAll')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                const pdf = new jsPDF();
                var pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
                var height = 10
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  height += 7
                  if (height >= pageHeight-10) {
                    pdf.addPage()
                    height=10
                  }
                  pdf.text(data[i].FullName ,10 , height)
                }
                pdf.save(`AllNames.pdf`)
              })
          }
        </script>
                
  </div>
  <p id="resultHeader" class="resultHeader"></p>
    <div class="results" id="results">

    <script id="getAll"></script>
    <script>
      
      const form = document.querySelector('form');
      const resultsDiv = document.querySelector('#results');
      var search=0
      form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        setTimeout(5000)
        event.preventDefault();
        if  (search==0)
        {
          const formData = new FormData(form);
fetch('/getnames?' + new URLSearchParams(formData))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    const name =document.getElementById('name').value;
    const resultsDiv = document.querySelector('#results');
    const ul = document.createElement('li');
    document.getElementById("resultHeader").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("resultHeader").innerHTML=`Showing results for: ${name}`;
    resultsDiv.insertBefore(ul, resultsDiv.firstChild);
    console.log(data[0].FullName)
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = data[i].FullName;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  });
          search=1
        }
      else if (search==1)
      {
        var message=`Showing results for: `+ document.getElementById('name').value + `. Please refresh before searching again.`
        document.getElementById("resultHeader").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("resultHeader").innerHTML=message;
        search=3
      }
      else if (search==3)
      {
        return null
      }
    });
    </script>

    </div>
 
  </body>

  <footer>Footer content</footer>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are helpful, my apologies for the messy code, I have been a bit unorganized as I try different methods to fix the error.

I have tried using different libraries and drivers to contact my mssql database. When testing offline, I was most successful with this combo of mssql and msnodesqlv8. Other methods using just one of mssql or msnodesqlv8 also resulted in the same 500 error.

To ensure it wasn't a problem with how I was returning data from my route, I also tried sending a test array back from my route, such as: `var testArray= [{FullName: "John Doe"}, {FullName: "Jane Doe"}]`
This array returned as intended both offline and in the Azure application.

Additionally, I have tried various suggestions from other similar, but not identical issues that others have reported on forms here on stackoverflow as well as elsewhere, but have had no luck in finding my solution.

Comment: Have you considered specifying only one authentication method? When you give it a username and password you're telling it to use SQL Logon (password-based) authentication. When you specify `trustedConnection: true` you're telling it to use Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows authentication by passing in the current processes' authentication token.

Comment: Rather than concatenating string segments together to build a query (this is called "SQL Injection" and is an incredibly bad, highly insecure, thing to do) have a read through the [mssql Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#request) documentation and see how to use `.input()` and `.output()` parameters.

Comment: I definitely need to get the injection part figured out. This is my first time trying to make something like this so I wanted to get it working before I cleaned it all up. Thank you for the advice though. I'll give that a read!

When not specifying that trustedConnection, I was having an error that said "self-signed certificate"... Was having trouble getting around that

Comment: I should add that when only using trustedConnection, this issue has still occurred for me

Comment: The `trustedConnection` option is not the same as `trustServerCertificate`. The latter, in combination with `encrypt`, is what you're seeking to control the self-signed certificate behaviour. But I'd be very concerned if any Azure SQL servers were using self-signed certificates - or is this an SQL Server instance that you installed yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to add the below code as your database connection as it worked for me:-**

I have referred the below code from this [**MS Document.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?view=azuresql-mi&tabs=windows)

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: 'siliconuser', // better stored in an app setting such as process.env.DB_USER
    password: 'password', // better stored in an app setting such as process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    server: 'valleyserver.database.windows.net', // better stored in an app setting such as process.env.DB_SERVER
    port: 1433, // optional, defaults to 1433, better stored in an app setting such as process.env.DB_PORT
    database: 'valleydb1', // better stored in an app setting such as process.env.DB_NAME
    setTimeout: '3000',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default'
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}

/*
    //Use Azure VM Managed Identity to connect to the SQL database
    const config = {
        server: process.env["db_server"],
        port: process.env["db_port"],
        database: process.env["db_database"],
        authentication: {
            type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-vm'
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    }

    //Use Azure App Service Managed Identity to connect to the SQL database
    const config = {
        server: process.env["db_server"],
        port: process.env["db_port"],
        database: process.env["db_database"],
        authentication: {
            type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service'
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    }
*/

console.log("Starting...");
connectAndQuery();

async function connectAndQuery() {
    try {
        var poolConnection = await sql.connect(config);

        console.log("Reading rows from the Table...");
        var resultSet = await poolConnection.request().query(`Select * FROM OnlineCourses`);

        console.log(`${resultSet.recordset.length} rows returned.`);

        // output column headers
        var columns = "";
        for (var column in resultSet.recordset.columns) {
            columns += column + ", ";
        }
        console.log("%s\t", columns.substring(0, columns.length - 2));

        // ouput row contents from default record set
        resultSet.recordset.forEach(row => {
            console.log("%s\t%s", row.CategoryName, row.ProductName);
        });

        // close connection only when we're certain application is finished
        poolConnection.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

In app.js add the below import statement:-

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
```

Add the below set as route:-

```js
app.get('/query', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const poolConnection = await sql.connect(config);
        const resultSet = await poolConnection.request().query('SELECT * FROM OnlineCourses');
        res.json(resultSet.recordset);
        poolConnection.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    }
});
```

Create a config object for your sql database like below:-

```js
const config = {
    user: 'siliconuser',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'valleyserver.database.windows.net',
    port: 1433,
    database: 'valleydb1',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
};
```

Comment: Trying to give this a go. However, I get a self-signed certificate error here. I'm gonna try to see if I can sort out how to get past that.

Comment: Still failing after this, I'm afraid. Any time I include a route that contacts a database it gives me that 500 error on Azure, even though I can host the site locally just fine. I appreciate your suggestion though; I had not found that MS document during my searching!

Comment: Actually, on a second deployment to Azure, I can get the main page of the site to load now. That's progress! Having issues actually communicating with the database now, but I think that is because of difficulties passing my domain credentials through. I'll work through that more

Comment: Okay, The above method should ideally work, Refer this SO thread answer on the similar issue-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798618/how-to-connect-an-existing-nodejs-server-app-to-azure-sql-database

Comment: In any case, the code you put above got me going, so I'll mark that as the solution. Thank you so much for the quick answer!